# Can't retrieve the text inside of span element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the value inside the span element and then change it like this:

```
 chatHub.client.someFunction = function (id) {
        var messagesCount = $("#" + id + "COUNT").text();
        messagesCount++;
        $("#" + id + "COUNT").text(messagesCount);

    }
```

This function is called every time the user sent a message. But here's the problem: `messagesCount` retrieves the wrong number and nothing changes in the HTML-code of the page after its function called.

[image: span id]

`someFunction()` successfully receiving this `Some roomCOUNT` and this `id` is a unique name of the room, where the users communicate and I can't figure out what's wrong with it. What could be the reason of receiving the wrong data in this field `var messagesCount = $("#" + id + "COUNT").text(); //it received 1, instead of 0`

Comment: Try casting the value to Integer before incrementing `Number($("#" + id + "COUNT").text())`.

Comment: why there are spaces in id ?

Comment: @JitendraMeena they souldn't be there? You mean that's the problem?

Comment: Remove the spaces from the id

Comment: or use `_` instead of space

Comment: so what's the reason that `messagesCount` received 1, instead of `null`

Comment: Great question Lab Lab, that's the most interesting part of this post.  var test = $(".tester").text();   console.log("Type of selector result: ", typeof(test)); test++;  console.log("Incremented: ", test);    //  Try that code. .text() would return an empty string since it did not find the actual element. If you add a number to a string in javascript it will cast to an integer, resulting in "1" in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No spaces are allowed in an id. See example below.

The id attribute value must begin with a letter (a–z or A–Z). That can be followed by any combination of letters (a–z or A–Z), digits (0–9), hyphens (-), underscores (_), colons (:), and periods (.).

The id value is also case sensitive, so `<span id="test">This is me</span>` and `<span id="TEST">This is me</span>` would be considered to be separate elements.

Use console.log to debug your code. It's very valuable to understand where it's failing.

```js
function getData (id) {
  console.log("Getting data from id of: " + id);
  
  var messagesCount = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
  console.log("Messages count: ", messagesCount);
  
  messagesCount++;
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = messagesCount;
}
    
// Shorthand for $( document ).ready()
$(function() {
  getData('some room 45');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="some room 45">0</span>
```

Comment: how can I replace those spaces and combine the separated words?

Comment: Do you not have control over the HTML? It's invalid and shouldn't be coming through in that format.

Comment: The function is receiving this `id` from the server like `"Some room name"`

Comment: Updated to retrieve with an invalid id.